# form open after error message

Tags: vba, ms-access, dialog

I have a few textboxes with hyperlinks in access that give the following error when clicked 'unable to open http.... Cannot download the information you requested'.

Well I have found a way to circumvent the error and get the hyperlinks to work.But what i want is that when the users click on the link and the error appears,once the user clicks OK I want a form to appear that guides them through the 2 steps needed to circumvent the error.Is that possible?

I mean is it possible for access to detect that the hyperlink has not worked and the file has not opened and subsequently open the instruction form after the user clicks OK from the error msgbox?

Appreciate the help.Please let me know if i need to elaborate further.

Comment: what is the error number??

Comment: You have to trap the error and handle it. Look into `On Error`. Can't help more without more information.

Comment: Thanks for the respons.. @raymond see there is no error number just the message 'unable to open http://...... .Cannot download the information you requested'

Comment: @sunknight Thanks for the response, I did try to have a message box on error that wud ask the user to read the instructions first but on debuggin i realised the debugger jus doesnt reach the error handling part..maybe access fails to recognise the issue as error

Comment: That is probably because the error happens outside Access on a browser. One thing you can try to do is use VBA to make an http request to the link before you let the user click on it. Then you can test whether it works or not programmatically.

Comment: You werer right it happens in the browser so access cannot identify it...I just included a set of instructions that the users should follow to circumvent the error